# Why Teams CallQueue does not call resource account?

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

**Goal:
When a call arrives my call queue an internal number should get called always.**

This internal number is a teams bot. I can call the number of the bot manually and everything work as expected.

**Setup:**

- Teams Call-Queue (with an internal number assigned, let's say +1)
- Resource Account (a bot with an internal number assigned, let's say +2)

Via Powershell I added the resource account (bot) to the Call-Queue as desciribed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab101ab9-5903-4b99-9943-8428bf517bb7/add-resource-account-to-call-queue-in-teams-using-powershell?forum=msteams). It's displayed correctly in the teams admin center.

When I call +2 (the bot), everything works correctly. When I call +1 (the queue) I see the bot (which is a member of the queue) never get called.

**Why resource accounts inside a call-queue not getting called?**

Thanks a lot for your response :-)

As you can see, the bot is part of the call-queue:

```html
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstance                                                                 

RunspaceId        : 13e7e999-e138-4a63-8d71-11111111
ObjectId          : a7009e96-c708-4ec8-a7c6-9999999999
TenantId          : 99ac6f3f-3560-4068-a677-00000000000
UserPrincipalName : 1@onmicrosoft.com
ApplicationId     : 99cd3e2e-fccb-99ad-ad00-888888888
DisplayName       : Call Queue
PhoneNumber       : tel:+1

RunspaceId        : 13e7e2a5-e138-4a63-8d71-222222222
ObjectId          : a2d8457b-990e-4db1-b8da-33333333333
TenantId          : 99ac6f3f-3560-4068-a677-00000000000
UserPrincipalName : 2@mydomain.com
ApplicationId     : d95c4ccb-8c9e-4adb-a4f0-777777777
DisplayName       : Bot
PhoneNumber       : tel:+2

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CsCallQueue                                                                                 

TenantId                                       : 99ac6f3f-3560-4068-a677-00000000000
Name                                           : Call Queue
Identity                                       : 1b550ab2-f49d-4331-a373-000233000009
Agents                                         : a2d8457b-990e-4db1-b8da-33333333333, OptIn
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below links for more details of the CallQueue. [link1](https://ucstatus.com/2019/05/14/how-to-assign-a-direct-routing-number-to-an-auto-attendant-or-call-queue-in-microsoft-teams-phone-system/)
[link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/manage-resource-accounts#create-a-resource-account-in-powershell)

the issue is when calling +1
could you please remove this number and reset to the call queue or auto attendant.
could you please confirm is it a hybrid licence number or any direct routing inplace.

Comment: I did exactly what you link1 describe. My goal is that my Resource Account is a member of the call queue (always get called when the call queue recive a call)